# SQL: create new field, populate with query results

Tags: sql, field, populate

I have two tables: tbl_listings, with the column: prop_id;
and another table: tbl_bookings, with the columns: prop_id, booking_date.

I want to write a query that counts all the times prop_id appears in tbl_bookings, and then populates a new column in tbl_listings with the results of that query.

my query looks like:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_listings
ADD COLUMN prop_count INT

UPDATE tbl_listings
    SET prop_count =
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl_bookings
    GROUP BY prop_id)
```

but for some reason I get an error saying: Subquery returns more than 1 row.
How do I fix this?

Comment: I think if you add a column to a table and then immediately try to update it the query will not run.  You need to use GO after adding the column

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sub-query gives you a count for each distinct `prop_id`. You can only assign one count value to `prop_count`. If you intended to update the `prop_count` in multiple rows that correspond to prop_ids, you will need to add a correlated subquery to your update that correlates the `prop_id` in `tbl_bookings` with the corresponding `prop_id` in `tbl_listings`.

As I think about your question more, I am wondering if you meant to insert into an empty tbl_listings table rather than update. You can do that with this command:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_listings(prop_id,prop_count)
SELECT prop_id, COUNT(*) as prop_count
FROM tbl_bookings
GROUP BY prop_id
```

If you really meant to update and assuming that each `prop_id` is present in your `tbl_listings` table, you can issue the following update:

```
UPDATE tbl_listings
SET prop_count=(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM tbl_bookings AS TB
                WHERE TB.prop_id=TL.prop_id)
FROM tbl_listings AS TL
```

If you want to update `tbl_listings` by inserting new prop_ids from `tbl_bookings` and their respective counts, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_listings(prop_id,prop_count)
SELECT prop_id, COUNT(*) as prop_count
FROM tbl_bookings AS TB
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT prop_id -- Insert only new prop_ids/counts
                 FROM tbl_listings AS TL 
                 WHERE TL.prop_id=TB.prop_id)
GROUP BY prop_id
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! I'm having trouble writing this WHERE clause. Do you think you could show me an example?

Comment: Just updated my answer with some samples depending on your case in order to more specifically help you out...

Comment: Great examples, walking through different possible situations. Very useful, thanks !