# How to make the joined data column as a new column in one table

Tags: database, postgresql, join

I have two tables A and B. Table A has the format like below:

```
id       task_start_time            task_end_time
__       _______________            _____________
1       2017-03-21 00:09:10     2017-03-21 00:12:18
1       2017-03-21 00:12:19     2017-03-21 00:12:56
1       2017-03-21 00:12:57     2017-03-21 00:13:10
2       2017-03-21 10:09:10     2017-03-21 10:25:34
2       2017-03-21 10:25:34     2017-03-21 11:09:10
2       2017-03-21 11:09:10     2017-03-21 11:21:39
3       2017-03-21 12:09:10     2017-03-21 12:19:19
3       2017-03-21 12:19:19     2017-03-21 12:29:19
3       2017-03-21 12:29:10     2017-03-21 12:39:10
```

Table B has the format like this

```
id          task_end_time                previous_task_end_time

__          _____________                ______________________
1          2017-03-21 00:12:18             NA
1          2017-03-21 00:12:56             2017-03-21 00:12:18 
1          2017-03-21 00:13:10             2017-03-21 00:12:56
2          2017-03-21 10:25:34             2017-03-21 10:25:34
2          2017-03-21 11:09:10             2017-03-21 11:09:10
2          2017-03-21 11:21:39             2017-03-21 11:21:39
3          2017-03-21 12:19:19             2017-03-21 12:19:19
3          2017-03-21 12:29:19             2017-03-21 12:29:19
3          2017-03-21 12:39:10             2017-03-21 12:39:10
```

Now I need to have the table A in this format

```
id       task_start_time            task_end_time        previous_task_end_time

__       _______________            _____________       ______________________
1       2017-03-21 00:09:10     2017-03-21 00:12:18             NA
1       2017-03-21 00:12:19     2017-03-21 00:12:56             2017-03-21 00:12:18 
1       2017-03-21 00:12:57     2017-03-21 00:13:10             2017-03-21 00:12:56
2       2017-03-21 10:09:10     2017-03-21 10:25:34             2017-03-21 10:25:34
2       2017-03-21 10:25:34     2017-03-21 11:09:10             2017-03-21 11:09:10
2       2017-03-21 11:09:10     2017-03-21 11:21:39             2017-03-21 11:21:39
3       2017-03-21 12:09:10     2017-03-21 12:19:19             2017-03-21 12:19:19
3       2017-03-21 12:19:19     2017-03-21 12:29:19             2017-03-21 12:29:19
3       2017-03-21 12:29:10     2017-03-21 12:39:10             2017-03-21 12:39:10
```

I know I can do a inner join them by id and start_time but how to save the resulting previous_end_time as a new column in A? Any help is appreciated

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151372/sql-create-new-field-populate-with-query-results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create the new column `previous_end_time` in table `a`.

```
ALTER TABLE a ADD COLUMN previous_end_time TIMESTAMP;
```

Then update the column.

```
UPDATE a SET previous_end_time = b.previous_task_end_time
FROM b WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.task_end_time = b.task_end_time
```

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Without the detail, no one can resolve your problem.

Comment: I tried with `A as (select * from public.A), B as (select * from public.B) update A set previous_end_time from B where A.id = B.id and A.task_end_time=B.task_end_time`  but it throws relation A does not exists

Comment: Then there probably is no table `a` (but in your question you said that there is).

Comment: there is public.A in my database

Comment: Use `"A"` instead of `A`